# Xpath in python not getting data

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm trying to request data from wikipedia in python using xpath.
I'm getting an empty list. What am I doing wrong.

```
import requests

from lxml import html

pageContent=requests.get(
     'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_judo'
)

tree = html.fromstring(pageContent.content)

name = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a[1]/text()')

print name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common mistake when trying to get the `xpath` from the browser and the `table` tags, as the browser is the one that normally adds the `tbody` tag inside of them, which doesn't actually exist inside the response body.

So just remove it and it should be like:

```
'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]//tr[2]/td[2]/a[1]/text()'
```

Comment: Awsome that worked thanks, what about something like this https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=btc-nxt. Im trying to get the xpath data for the price in dollars //*[@id="rowChart"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/text(). But its also giving me a blank value

Comment: @TarikKoric that's a totally different question and a total different case, first is it protected by cloudflare so getting any kind of data from that site will be extremely difficult and also looks like the entire site is generated dynamically with javascript, so a normal request won't work.